# ComboBox shows System.Data.DataRowView first

Tags: c#, database, dbnull, datarowview

So in windowsform I have 2 `ComboBoxes` and one `CheckedListBox` for exercises. When you select your typefitness (calisthenics, weights, cardio, etc.) and your musclegroup (tricep, chest, back, forearms, etc.) than you should get the exercises out of the `CheckedListBox`.

Both `ComboBoxes'` default values are 1, so it should show something like pushups in the `CheckedListBox`, because `TypeFitness` = 1 is Calisthenics and `MuscleGroup` = 1 is Front Shoulder.

Instead it shows `System.Data.DataRowView`, but the second time I select Calisthenics in the form it shows the right thing. Is there a way to make it so it shows the exercises immediately?

(`System.Data.DataRowView` only shows when the previous selection didn't have an outcome)

Code:

```
private void Exercises()
{
    string query = "SELECT X.ExerciseId, X.Naam FROM Xercises AS X " +
            "INNER JOIN MG_Exercise AS MGX ON MGX.ExerciseId = X.ExerciseId " +
            "WHERE MGX.MuscleId = @MuscleId AND X.FitnessId = @FitnessId";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MuscleId", comBoxMuscleGroup.SelectedValue);
        SqlParameter param2 = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FitnessId", comBoxTypeFitness.SelectedValue);

        if(param.Value == null)
        {
            param.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        if(param2.Value == null)
        {
            param2.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        DataTable Xdata = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(Xdata);

        clbXcercises.DisplayMember = "Naam";
        clbXcercises.ValueMember = "X.ExerciseId";
        clbXcercises.DataSource = Xdata;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but here is not the entire code, where are you handling what data you should get from server?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I just initialize all the methods in button events and the form itself.

Comment: Which combobox shows `System.Data.DataRowView` first? What does `first` mean? First time form loads? Or first time combobox is bound to the data table? When the combobox is bound first time to the data table?

Comment: `System.Data.DataRowView` show in the `CheckedListBox` when the form loads and when the previous `TypeFitness` and `MuscleGroup` don't have an outcome. So it only shows in the `CheckedListBox` where exercises are put in. (edited it a little bit)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I put `DataSource` last `Exercises()`. So it should be:

```
clbXcercises.DataSource = Xdata;
clbXcercises.DisplayMember = "Naam";
clbXcercises.ValueMember = "X.ExerciseId";
```